# Linear Algebra: Why this is not a reduced row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know, the following $4\times 1$ matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

are in reduced row echelon form, but why is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

not in row echelon form?

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Is the matrix above in reduced row echelon form? If so, how so? Could you explain to me?

Thanks!

Comment: In your $3^{rd}$ matrix, you should swap lines $1$ and $3$ and in the $4^{th}$, swap $2$ and $3$ and then $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Did you [look up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-reduced_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) the definition? It's easier and faster than asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual definition requires that all zero rows are below all non-zero rows.

To check a matrix is in reduced row echelon form, you should check:

1. All zero rows are below all non-zero rows.
2. The first non-zero entry in each non-zero row is strictly to the right of that in the previous row. (This condition is empty for the first row).
3. The first non-zero entry in each non-zero row is a $1$.
4. The other entries in the columns containing these initial $1$s are all $0$.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-reduced_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) an non-identity permutation matrix is not RREF. However such matrices satisfy all your conditions.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks, I missed a condition.

Comment: thanks! my textbook is missing the first condition... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just put the zeroes at the bottom!